# Duplicate GET requests to OAuth flow redirect URI

Tags: facebook, session, redirect, oauth

I'm seeing a very strange issue with OAuth2 based social logins on my website. A small percentage of social login users are being redirected TWICE to the redirect URI used during the OAuth2 flow:

[image]

NOTE: This is not logging error, I'm seeing plenty of OAuth redirects which are hitting my servers just once.

This is also happening across a range of OAuth providers including Facebook and Google.

When I'm able to reproduce this in Chrome, I see the first request to the redirect_uri is cancelled in browser and the second request goes through successfully. This creates a small window for a race condition where the first request changes the session key on the server after successful login (to avoid session fixation vulnerabilities), so that when the second request hits the server with the old session key, it is missing state information in the session and the OAuth flow fails.

I have absolutely no clue what could be causing this as it's happening after the users are redirected to the 3rd party OAuth providers. Have you seen something similar on your production environments?

Comment: _“it's happening after the users are redirected to the 3rd party OAuth providers”_ - that sounds rather impossible; a request can not be answered with _two_ responses, the remote party can only redirect you once. Plus, the value of the code parameter is different in both requests, so that really indicates that in all likelihood it is your app that is making two requests to the login endpoint somehow.

Comment: @CBroe Assuming it's my app that is at fault — I'm still only seeing one login popup. I'm entering my FB credentials only once and pressing enter only once. Why are my logs saying the redirect URI is being hit twice then?

Comment: How should I know, how should anyone here know? No on here know what your app does. What have you done so far to debug this then? Have you checked what is going on client-side, via browser dev tools?